# OIDC/Identity 4 - Getting unexpected 401 errors

Tags: angular, identityserver4, openid-connect

Here is my basic design:
Angular 7 front end using OIDC Javascript library for security
.NET Core v2 API for all data layer work
.NET Core Identity 4 Server for OAuth (separate server from API)

I am getting a lot of unexpected 401 errors.  These should not be happening, the user is authorized, I can see the user authorized in the log.  So I can only think it must be some type of a timing issue, or setup issue.  Security works most of the time, lets say 90% to 95% of the time it works fine, so my basic setup is good.  I don't know what it can be other than a timing issue.

Here is my OIDC Config:

```
    const config = {
    clockSkew: 60*60*24*365*100,    // Effectively disable clock skew
    authority: Endpoint.STSAuthority,
    client_id: Constants.clientKey,
    redirect_uri: `${location.protocol}//${location.host}/assets/loginRedirect.html`,
    scope: `openid profile ${Constants.apiKey} `,
    response_type: 'id_token token',
    post_logout_redirect_uri: `${location.protocol}//${location.host}/assets/logoutRedirect.html`,
    userStore: new WebStorageStateStore({ store: window.localStorage }),
    automaticSilentRenew: true,
    staleStateAge: 60 * 60,        // 60 minutes
    accessTokenExpiringNotificationTime: 60 * 2,    // 2 minutes
    silent_redirect_uri: `${location.protocol}//${location.host}/assets/silentRedirect.html`
    };
```

Here is my STS config:

```
    new Client
    {
    ClientId = $"Example-STS-{this._programSettings.Site}",
    ClientName = $"Example {this._programSettings.Site} STS",
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
    RequireConsent = false,
    RedirectUris = this._securitySection.RedirectUris,
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = this._securitySection.PostLogoutRedirectUris,
    AllowedCorsOrigins = new List<string> { this._securitySection.AllowFrom },
    AllowedScopes =
    {
    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
    $"Example-API-{this._programSettings.Site}"
    },
    IdentityTokenLifetime=60*30,  // 30 minutes
    AccessTokenLifetime=60*60*2,  // 2 hours
    }
```

Here is a dump of my OIDC object at time of 401 Unauthorized (personal information was removed):

```
    User: {
    "_settings": {
        "_response_type": "id_token",
        "_scope": "openid",
        "_filterProtocolClaims": true,
        "_loadUserInfo": true,
        "_staleStateAge": 900,
        "_clockSkew": 3153600000,
        "_userInfoJwtIssuer": "OP",
        "_stateStore": {
            "_store": {
                "authContext": {
                    "loginKey": "68F7AD86DE3B427C98B02DF1BE7D9959",
                    "id": "5d77965b-e874-45e1-bb1f-08a6eaf2e773"
                },
                "oidc.b0add291aa304938b8246800c7729912": {
                    "id": "b0add291aa304938b8246800c7729912",
                    "created": 1555734037,
                    "nonce": "5476718e1373406bab9e452b8f9dbf31",
                    "redirect_uri": "https://www.example.com/assets/silentRedirect.html",
                    "authority": "https://prodsts.example.com:4252/",
                    "client_id": "example-STS-Prod"
                },
                "oidc.user:https://prodsts.example.com:4252/:example-STS-Prod": {
                    "id_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjhhZjhkODA0ZGNlNWI3NjZjODZlZTJmZjRhYzY4YWMwIiwidHlwIjoiSldUIn0.eyJuYmYiOjE1NTU3MjUwNzIsImV4cCI6MTU1NTcyNjg3MiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9wcm9kc3RzLmJvb21lcmFuZ2RtLmNvbTo0MjUyIiwiYXVkIjoiQm9vbWVyYW5nRE0tU1RTLVByb2QiLCJub25jZSI6IjdjMDE2ZWJiZWJlYzRiNjg5Y2U5NTMwOTkyYmQxMGI3IiwiaWF0IjoxNTU1NzI1MDcyLCJhdF9oYXNoIjoid3p4LTQtRlhFNnJOSkQ1ZjI3M1BTUSIsInNpZCI6ImM2ZWVjZTg4NmQ1NGFhZTY2YmYxOWYwNDk4NTljMjhiIiwic3ViIjoiNWQ3Nzk2NWItZTg3NC00NWUxLWJiMWYtMDhhNmVhZjJlNzczIiwiYXV0aF90aW1lIjoxNTU1NjkxNTQ0LCJpZHAiOiJsb2NhbCIsImFtciI6WyJwd2QiXX0.fBdgtLfWwnlLoi-T21c2VP2Wqt2fHo6l3eV_FKiXpyqrpdzAxqxOintXec-SJK1LwChMdy966xCFlVYp6jm5XwTfTPBPshNYeBPx9O0QOA0JYL33LvMGmgl4igV_wTscIPq6qnBpd75nagSvWT-IZgByxSygmh-JIuBQVqJPOpneoZCtLaeaVIyNzxLbCozc_pEc-kVqHGRbYEmDxU5mGdCdaKjAi0dCfJ3D3mDN8joQfwtK8PEuCKa5CPMgymkRAEJpfTY39DklLurUNyBKA9fJ6J95ys1dF3McgqEwdOZv37s2IialwpeYXOsFPlwpOh9_cvV5dS2wDav9H56pqA",
                    "session_state": "UCh5OQis7ikprYhHbUpjeS0GVMQ4S8XD2OrzA0Am4wU.0bd43c3337b6dc18bc7e7020f1f6ecb8",
                    "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjhhZjhkODA0ZGNlNWI3NjZjODZlZTJmZjRhYzY4YWMwIiwidHlwIjoiSldUIn0.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.sA0ST_9pka0jqlG7P1gAguGUm2mQ--swVP7cRJ9vC6eFYhW1bkQXEkdF0NkA9Ks0olOkERlwqN6etLfO7rB01RtugDOLzcr9OJgw7ScgaGDlS7oVH0R_ElEXLoE9iPqUfH2fQpV-CtIyGBC3Ceapvv0OqZUZgGkpZR_bRTUfOKCGdfSa1syESeoW5-JhL_8-AhLBRjH8jILMk5iUAkGgPkMtvRp3qudvhpLmp1Ya_l9-QO192P3bMifrqj7ABCzjucffiuNrApalWTCv_K7HbdMXWMwuF6mGjLO75GwsGMMHl7vAl6sGu7N1HaWRRTVViQb_YiwxgqJhlJ1zRxvQnQ",
                    "token_type": "Bearer",
                    "scope": "openid profile example-API-Prod",
                    "profile": {
                        "sid": "c6eece886d54aae66bf19f049859c28b",
                        "sub": "5d77965b-e874-45e1-bb1f-08a6eaf2e773",
                        "auth_time": 1555691544,
                        "idp": "local",
                        "amr": [
                            "pwd"
                        ],
                        "AspNet.Identity.SecurityStamp": "H2GPEWKAHVYVQM6HGOWXAUHMUZPRMN5G",
                        "ExampleId": "12679",
                    },
                    "expires_at": 1555728667
                }
            },
            "_prefix": "oidc."
        },
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll definately have a problem with ClockSkew:

```
clockSkew: 60*60*24*365*100,    // Effectively disable clock skew
```

The value of clock skew should be within minutes of the token expiration, because it's only meant to account for asynchronous clocks.

What do you expect when you have an access token with a lifetime of two hours and a clockskew of 100 years? For how long should the user be authenticated?

I can imagine that at some point (after token expiration) the token is refused.

You should set the clockskew to five minutes (the default) or less and probably use [refresh tokens](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-parecki-oauth-browser-based-apps-02#section-8).

Comment: The problem is, with the clock skew set to a small number, we are getting dozens of complaints of people who can't log in, because they apparently don't know how to set their PC time.  I had no choice but to disable clock skew, because we were having too many issues with it. Isn't the only purpose of clock skew to basically check the expiration of the token, based on client time v server time?  What do you mean I should probably use refresh tokens, I am?

Comment: Isn't this value basically doing my refresh token, with the silent renew?
 automaticSilentRenew: true,

To expand upon my first comment.  I originally had clock skew taking the default, which I think was 5 minutes.  But my website owner didn't have his pc time synced, and his clock was about 7 minutes off.  He could never log in, until I disabled clock skew.  (Yes, it would have been better to convince him to sync his time, but he took the position that if it happened to him, it would happen to others)

Comment: Really? I can't imagine so many users have an invalid time nowadays. Most machines have an automatic sync. Are you sure the time on your machine is in sync? Because otherwise it seems logical to assume that those users also experience these problems with other websites. Can you check the actual expiration time of the access token (e.g. using jwt.io).

Comment: I mentioned the refresh token because you're using the [Implicit flow](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/grant_types.html#implicit) (which doesn't allow refresh tokens) and you didn't configured it for your client: `AllowOfflineAccess = true`. I've linked to the draft because there are some movements concerning how to secure a SPA. Please read [this](https://brockallen.com/2019/01/03/the-state-of-the-implicit-flow-in-oauth2/) and [this](https://leastprivilege.com/2019/01/18/an-alternative-way-to-secure-spas-with-asp-net-core-openid-connect-oauth-2-0-and-proxykit/).

Comment: When I let clock skew set to the default time, it failed for the guy writing the checks, plus (per him) a few other people he knew.  So when the guy writing the checks tells you to turn off that checking, that's what you do.  It always worked 100% for me, but I've been using NIST for about 2 or 3 decades.
How do other people handle it when the users time is off by 7 to 10 minutes?  I agree, in this day and age, having manual time settings, is about as senseless as using a curling iron to make toast, but I write the code, I don't always get to make the decisions about the best direction.

Comment: This whole Identity 4 setup is new to me.  I've used Identity for nearly a decade, (forms auth before that), but this is the first website I've ever used Identity 4 on.  It's been a rough road, because it's so incredibly exacting, that one tiny mistake, and nothing works, and you don't know why half the time.  Forms auth was so much simpler, but then, that's why it was so much less secure.

I'm going to work on this yet tonight, and update this ticket tomorrow.  Thanks

Comment: You can't disable clock skew. It is not really a check. It's just a way to add extra time (100 years) to an expired access token, which effectively means that the token should always be accepted, even when it is long time expired. You really should bring it to a minimum, say 10 minutes. But I don't understand how a new issued token, that expires in two hours, is invalid after login in the first place. Are you setting times in the token manuallY? How can auth_time be `Fri Apr 19 2019 18:32:24 GMT+0200` and expiration time `Sat Apr 20 2019 04:51:12 GMT+0200`? That is more than two hours.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192238/discussion-between-ruard-van-elburg-and-brian-kitt).

Comment: So I removed the clock skew, let it take the default of '5 minutes', and today we had 9 different times where logins were rejected due to 'iat is in the future'.  I read the code for OIDC, and I have to increase clock skew to avoid that problem.  So taking the default of 5 minutes turned out to be bad advice.  
Also, the unexpected '401 Unauthorized' continue to happen all day long.

Comment: I got rid of the implicit flow and went with the 'code' flow.  I would have rather gone with a 'refresh token' flow, but there appears to be no way to do that.This did nothing to stop my problems.  Again, turns out to be bad advice . I still have a gut feel that there is something inherently unstable in .NET Core identity 4.
What else can I do to stop the problems.  If I can't figure this out, I have no choice but to dump Identity 4, it's simply too unstable to use.  How do other people get rid of all of the extraneous '401 Unauthorized' problems, this is a huge issue for us on our website.